# how to access django object in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I want to access django object in ajax code. But i am unable to access it. please guide me.

> my server code

```
def attendance_table(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            CollegeCode = request.session.get('collegeCode')
            academicyear = logic.academicYearCal()
            eventquery = "SELECT e.EventId , e.EventLocation,e. EventStartDate,e.EventEndDate,e.EventHours,em.EventCode as EC ,em.EventName from Events "
            events = models.Events.objects.raw(eventquery, [academicyear, '1', CollegeCode])

            context = {}
            events = serializers.serialize('json', events)
            context['events'] = events

            return JsonResponse(data=context)

        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse(data={'error':'error'})
```

> Ajax Code

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(response) {
            console.log(response.events);
        }
    });
```

in browser console the output is

```
[{"model": "sample.events", "pk": "E22", "fields": {"eventcode": "1", "collegecode": "KIT", "eventopenflag": "1", "eventstartdate": "2017-07-23", "eventenddate": "2017-07-22", "eventlocation": "Shivaji memorials , kolhapur", "academicyear": "2017", "eventlevel": 5, "eventhours": 0}}]
```

correct me please..

Comment: The `response.events` is a JS array with JS object(s) inside it. What exactly you want to access?

Comment: everything in **"fields": {"eventcode": "1", "collegecode": "KIT", "eventopenflag": "1", "eventstartdate": "2017-07-23", "eventenddate": "2017-07-22", "eventlocation": "Shivaji memorials , kolhapur", "academicyear": "2017", "eventlevel": 5, "eventhours": 0}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [access a javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) similarly to a python dictionary.

Because you're returning an array, you must, first, iterate over it. Assuming you named your returning array as `response.events`, then:

```
success:function(response) {
    // convert String to JSON object (JS object)
    var events = JSON.parse(response.events);  // events should be an Array (console.log(events instanceof Array) should yield True)
    for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) { 
        // now each events[i] has an object within it
        var obj = events[i];  // obj is an alias for each object in the array
        // Now you can access each key-value pair like this
        var fields = obj.fields;  // an alias again
        var eventcode = fields.eventcode;  // or fields['eventcode']
        var collegecode = fields.collegecode;
        // etc.
    }
```

Note that if your array is always going to include one object, then you don't need a for loop. Just get the object inside it like this:

```
success:function(response) {
    var events = JSON.parse(response.events);
    var obj = events[0];
    var fields = obj.fields;
    ...
}
```

Comment: **var obj = response.events[i];** with this i got only **[** as a output and rest  all are undefined. why so ? is it not serialized properly?

Comment: Does `console.log(response.events);` inside `success` prints `[{"model":.....}]` ??

Comment: What I wrote in my answer should be put inside `function(response)`.

Comment: console output for **response.events[0]** is **TypeError:response.events is undefined**

Comment: What is the output of `response.events[0].constructor` ??

Comment: **function String()**